# Preferred way to use the random class

Tags: java, random

What is the preferred way to use the `Random` class in Java ?

a) Create one object of `Random` and use it many times

b) Create a new object of `Random` each time a random value is needed

What are the drawbacks and beneftis ?

Comment: If you choose a, then you have some memory overhead. If you choose b, then you have performance overhead. The overhead is in both cases,  depending on what you do, may be negligible or significant.

Comment: If you're worried about the "randomness" of your numbers, you can just reseed the `Random` object - which is a much simpler operation than creating an entirely new object. `myRandom.setSeed( System.currentTimeMillis() );`

Comment: @Jamie Thats actually a bad idea. Because there is _no explicit guarantee that the resulting stream of values would meet the same statistical definition of randomness_ . See Dave Costas answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, the guarantee made by the class is that a single instance will produce a pseudorandom stream of values.  With your method (b), there's no explicit guarantee that the resulting stream of values would meet the same statistical definition of randomness.  So if you care about true statistical randomness, (a) would be preferred.

I don't see much benefit to (b).  I suppose it means you don't need to hold onto a reference to a single instance of Random, but doing that in a singleton class would be straightforward.  Generally I would be wary of creating lots of new objects for performance reasons, but you could measure the impact and decide whether it was acceptable.

So between these options I would usually prefer (a).

I can see a third option, of using more than one long-lived instance.  You might do that if you have multiple threads and you want each to use its own `Random` object.  (It's unclear to me from the javadoc what the implication are of having multiple threads calling a single object might be.)

Comment: Quote: "there's no explicit guarantee that the resulting stream of values would meet the same statistical definition of randomness". This would be especially true when using the same seed. :) (happened to me once ...)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to repeatedly generate random numbers in a **loop**, then you can create a `Random` object and use it to generate numbers. There is barely any reason to create a new `Random` object for every random number. Doing so may degrade the performance of the program unnecessarily.

If you generate random numbers once in a while, then it doesn't hurt to create a new Random object for each time you generate random number. Keeping a `Random` object around is also OK. Note that this may mix with the case above: for example, you may generate many random numbers at the start of a game, but no random thing happens during the game.

With the Java virtual machine, I have a bit of doubt about the memory usage that can be saved by not keeping a `Random` object throughout the lifetime of the program. On the other hand, there is definitely performance hit if `Random` object is always re-created. The overhead might or might not be visible, depending on what the program does.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good ones. especially the one from Dave Costa. I just have one thing to add.

Who do you want to see the random behavior? the programmer or the end user?

Using 1 Random object with a static seed, means that you will always be able do the same actions and get the same results (Random is psuedo-random not actually random). This is a wonder for debugging and trying to reproduce reported errors!